# Linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, derivatives, transformation

Let $\vec{f}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\vec{f} (\vec{x}) = (x+y^2, x^3+5y)$ and $\vec{x} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\vec{h} = (h_1, h_2)$ and $\vec{a} = (1,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. How do I show that the derivative of $\vec{f}$ at $\vec{a}$ is the map

$A\vec{h} := \vec{f}' (\vec{a}) \vec{h} = (h_1 + 2h_2, 3h_1 + 5h_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{f(x)} &=&(x+y^{2},x^{3}+5y) \\
\partial _{x}\mathbf{f(x)} &=&(1,3x^{2}) \\
\partial _{y}\mathbf{f(x)} &=&(2y,5) \\
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{f(x)} &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2y \\
3x^{2} & 5%
\end{array}%
\right)  \\
(\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{f})\mathbf{(a)} &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 5%
\end{array}%
\right)  \\
\{(\partial _{\mathbf{x}}\mathbf{f)(a)\}h} &=&\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 5%
\end{array}%
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
h_{1} \\
h_{2}%
\end{array}%
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
h_{1}+2h_{2} \\
3h_{1}+5h_{2}%
\end{array}%
\right)
\end{eqnarray*}